# From Heisenberg to Schrodinger picture in second quantization formalism

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics

I'm a bit confused about the QM representations: I know that in the shrodinger picture, the operators stay the same, and the quantum state rotates in the hilbert space. In the heisenberg picture it's the operators that change, and the states stay always the same. Suppose the following

In the context of quantum optics, suppose you have  an input fields, in some state generated by $f(a, a^\dagger)$, that is, the input state is: $f(a, a^\dagger)|0\rangle=|\psi\rangle$. Now, the field will undergo a series of linear transformations such as beamsplitters, phase rotations, and squeezing stuff. Let's boil it all down to an operator $U$. Then I know that in the shrodinger picture, the final state is given by $|\psi_{out}\rangle=Uf(a, a^\dagger)|0\rangle$. If I were to talk about the Heisenberg picture then I would say that every field operator will be transformed as $U^\dagger a U$, therefore I would be able to write $f(U^\dagger a U, U^\dagger a^\dagger U)=f^\prime $.

**The questionable argument:**

Now, suppose I want to find the output state $| \psi_{out}\rangle$. Since the vaccum state is the same in any representation, then the vacuum is the same before and after the transformations $U$. Since doing $U^\dagger a U$ is merely a change of basis, then $|\psi_{out}\rangle=f(U^\dagger a U, U^\dagger a^\dagger U) |0\rangle$

Is this correct reasoning?

Comment: I _think_ (this is why I am writing this as a comment) that the $U$ you are thinking about must be the unitary time evolution operator for it to be used while converting Schrödinger picture to Heisenberg picture since their difference is the _time evolution_ of states vs. observables.

Comment: It doesn't need to be the time evolution operator. It can be the beam splitter operator for example. I'm really coming at this from an optics approach. The doubt arose when looking into optical systems in the local oscillator approach (or quasi-modes, if I'm not mistaken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f'(a, a^\dagger) := f(U\,a\,U^\dagger, U\,a^\dagger\,U^\dagger)$. We expect $f'(a, a^\dagger) = U\,f(a, a^\dagger)\,U^\dagger$. Taylor expanding $f$ would give us terms in the form $K_n = x_1\,x_2\,x_3 \cdots x_n$ where $x_i \in \{a,a^\dagger\}$. Let $a \mapsto U\,a\,U^\dagger,\ a^\dagger \mapsto U\,a^\dagger\,U^\dagger$. This means all $x_i \mapsto U\,x_i\,U^\dagger$ as well. Letting all $x_i$ to transform we get $K_n' = U\,x_1\,U^\dagger\,U\,x_2\,U^\dagger\cdots U\,x_n\,U^\dagger = U\,K_n\,U^\dagger$. As such, all terms in the Taylor expansion will end up transforming the same way as the operator arguments, that is, **functions of operators transform exactly the same way as their arguments** for unitary transformations, that is, $f'(a,a^\dagger) = U\,f(a,a^\dagger)\,U^\dagger$. This means that your reasoning is indeed correct.

In Heisenberg picture, we would expect that if $|\psi\rangle = O |\phi\rangle$, transforming $|\psi\rangle \mapsto |\psi\rangle' = U\,|\psi\rangle$, $|\phi\rangle \mapsto |\phi\rangle' = U\,|\phi\rangle$, and $O \mapsto O' = U\,O\,U^\dagger$ would keep the equation form the same: $|\psi\rangle' = O'\,|\phi\rangle'$. Let $|\phi\rangle := |0\rangle$ and $O := f(a, a^\dagger)$. This means that the state being transformed is the original input state $|\psi\rangle$. You transform it via a unitary operator $U$ to $|\psi_{out}\rangle = U\,|\psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle'$. So the Heisenberg picture would dictate:

$$
|\psi_{out}\rangle = |\psi\rangle' = f'(a,a^\dagger)\,|\phi\rangle' = U\,f(a,a^\dagger)\,U^\dagger\,U\,|\phi\rangle = U\,f(a, a^\dagger)\,|\phi\rangle
$$

where we recovered your main equation. Putting the definition of $f'$ back and noting $U\,|0\rangle = |0\rangle$,

$$
|\psi_{out}\rangle = f'(a,a^\dagger)\,|\phi\rangle' = f(U\,a\,U^\dagger,U\,a^\dagger\,U^\dagger)\,U\,|0\rangle = f(U\,a\,U^\dagger,U\,a^\dagger\,U^\dagger)\,|0\rangle
$$

Comment: I know that the question "why is $U|0\rangle=|0\rangle$" is a whole other SE post, but would it be possible to explain why it is so? I said that it should be true because I was told it must be so, but I don't really grasp why

Comment: If $U$ is closed in Fock subspaces of a given particle count, $U\,|0\rangle = e^{i\phi}\,|0\rangle\ \exists \phi$. If not, then any $|\psi\rangle$ can be written as $U\,|0\rangle$ or so I've read. So your question might be better phrased as "Why does this optical operator preserve particle count?" and I honestly don't know good enough quantum optics to answer that.

Comment: I just don't understand what a closed operator is. If you could add a small bit on what that means, it would be awesome. I've already accepted the answer, because it's good. And also, the answer to the question "Why does this optical operator preserve particle count?" will be: there are systems that preserve particle count such as beamsplitters, phase rotations and mirrors. Those are the passive and linear systems. If I were to add a squeezing operator, then the particle number is not conserved, and no longer have that conservation. Hopefully this helps

Comment: Closed in this context means the following: Let there be a function $f: S \to S$. Choose a subset $A \subset S$. $f$ is closed in $A$ if $\forall x \in A,\ f(x) \in A$. In the context of linear operators, $S$ is a vector space, $A$ is a subspace and $f$ is a linear operator (e.g. $U$ or your $f$).